# Metric and harmonic map (or map between manifolds)

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, riemannian-geometry

There are many questions about what metric can be placed on a given manifold . For example , place a metric with non-negative curvature.

As I know , the Gauss-Bonnet theory is useful in this question. But in some question , the  Euler characteristic is not zero, then ,it is not useful for whether can be placed metric with non-negative or non-positive curvature. In fact ,I don't know the general method about this kind of question .

So, I think whether we can do it by studying the maps from given manifold to suitable manifold ? Are there any theory about this ?

This just be a soft question ,and my English is poor. So ,if there are any problem , tell me .

Comment: In what sense is the euler characteristic hard to get? It's the most easily computable topological invariant I can think of.

Comment: @MikeMiller  Yes, I have edit it. I just a beginner . I just want to know the general method about what metric can be placed and whether studying the maps between manifolds is useful .  I really a newcomer, so ,there is some not suitable words in my question, sorry.

Comment: Since you mentioned harmonic map in the title, I suggest that you read about the book "lectures on harmonic maps" by Rick and Yau. Especially on the proof of Frankel conjecture and on simply connected compact manfiold with positive isotopic curvatures.

Comment: @ArcticChar  I am sorry to ask where I can download it. The results of google just be the catalogue of lectures on harmonic maps.

Comment: I am talking about [this one](https://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Lectures_on_harmonic_maps.html?id=PlXvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y). Cant you find it in your library?